# How can I upgrade kernel to version 4.10 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I have an installed Ubuntu version 16.04 running with Kernel version 4.4.0-64-generic

How can I upgrade the kernel to 4.10?

Comment: **There is an easier way than the accepted answer**: install the **Hardware Enablement (HWE)** kernel, see package `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` or `linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`, read more here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Always remember** that might be an issue between a specific software and the latest Linux-kernel, for example the **VirtualBox** might not work like it should on the newest Linux-Kernel.

**I suggest you to wait** until the teams of the distros **Ubuntu 16.04** include the Linux-kernel **4.10.x** in the repositories or you can follow those two options:

**OPTION 1:** You can download the Debian packages of 4.10.1 Linux-Kernel from Ubuntu trusted sources and install them with the risk of some software that may not work like it should **since the programmer did not make it to work on the newest Linux-Kernel yet.**

**OPTION 2:** You can compiling it by yourself for using the **latest of the latest** version of Linux-Kernel for fun and learning.

---

### **Downloading and Installing the Debian Packages for 4.10.1 Linux-Kernel:**

---

### **For 32bit ONLY.**

In Terminal:

```
cd Desktop
mkdir linux_14.10.1
cd linux_14.10.1
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.1/linux-headers-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_i386.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.1/linux-image-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_i386.deb
```

**Install the 4.10.1 Linux-Kernel:**

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Update GRUB:**

```
sudo update-grub
```

Don't forget to install (to avoid any software error in the future) the "gcc" from synaptics according to the Linux-kernel x.xx version.

```
sudo reboot
```

Now choose to boot your 4.10.1 Linux-kernel from GRUB menu.

**REMOVING THE 4.10.1 LINUX-KERNEL:**

*Reboot to GRUB.*

*Choose to boot from your previous Linux-Kernel.*

Execute and choose to remove:

linux-headers-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_i386.deb

linux-image-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_i386.deb

---

### For 64bit ONLY.

In Terminal:

```
cd Desktop
mkdir linux_14.10.1
cd linux_14.10.1
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.1/linux-headers-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_amd64.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.1/linux-image-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_amd64.deb
```

**Install the 4.10.1 Linux-Kernel:**

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Update GRUB:**

```
sudo update-grub
```

Don't forget to install (to avoid any software error in the future) the "gcc" from synaptics according to the Linux-kernel x.xx version

```
Sudo reboot
```

Now choose to boot your 4.10.1 Linux-kernel from GRUB menu.

**REMOVING THE 4.10.1 LINUX-KERNEL:**

*Reboot to GRUB.*

*Choose to boot from your previous Linux-Kernel.*

Execute and choose to remove:

linux-headers-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_amd64.deb

linux-image-4.10.1-041001-generic_4.10.1-041001.201702260735_amd64.deb

Open a Terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

---

### **Compiling the newest Linux-Kernel for X86 architecture:**

**0. Downloading the Free-Source-Code:**

Go to  from https://www.kernel.org/ and choose the version of Linux-Kernel you wish
Move the downloaded ".tar.xz" Linux-Kernel to a optional named folder anywere you like.

Extract the ".tar.xz" Linux Kernel to the Desktop or anywhere you wish.
Open a Terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T:

`cd Desktop/Linux-x.x.x` (Linux-x.x.xis an example of the name of the folder of the extracted Linux-Kernel)

**1.INSTALLING THE NEEDED LIBRARIES:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential kernel-package libncurses5-dev bzip2 fakeroot gdebi grub-customizer
```

**2.KERNEL CONFIGURATION:**

In terminal:

`make menuconfig` (Choose the Options OR leave it as it is you can always go back to your previous Linux-kernel)

**Controls:**
Use the arrows Up,Down for the options.

Use **Enter** OR **Space** to choose an option.

Use **Left**,**Right** to Exit, Save, Help etc.

**Take your time** to explore the options (or leave them as it is) and Save,Exit.

**3.COMPILING THE LINUX-KERNEL:**

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-its-a-test kernel_image kernel_headers
```

(its-a-test is an example you can name it anything-you-like)

**Now wait** until the compiling finish, it will take some time according to your cpu for example a core2quad will take around to 45 minutes.

**4.INSTALLING THE NEW LINUX KERNEL:**
Install the two DEB packages that has been created into the extracted kernel folder it should be named something like  linux-headers-x.xx.deb and linux-image-x.xx.deb.

**DO NOT DELETED THOSE TWO DEB'S FILES IF YOU WANT TO INSTALL THEM ON ANOTHER PC OR IF YOU WANT TO REMOVE YOUR TEST LINUX-KERNEL LATER.**

`ls` (see the compiled *.deb files)

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**5.UPDATING GRUB:**

```
sudo update-grub
```

Don't forget to install (to avoid any software error in the future) the "gcc" from synaptics according to the kernel x.xx version.

```
Sudo reboot
```

Now choose to boot your test Linux-kernel from GRUB menu.

Open a Terminal:

`uname -a` (see the version and name of your test Linux-Kernel)

Congratulations!

---

**REMOVING YOUR TEST LINUX-KERNEL:**

*Reboot to GRUB.*

*Choose to boot from your previous Linux-Kernel*

*Execute  **linux-headers-x.xx.deb** and then the **linux-image-x.xx.deb** and choose to remove.*

Open a Terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```